# Adding a background image just below the navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I want to add a background image (having a full window sized width) just below the navigation bar. It should not cover the whole page length, but starts just below the navigation bar menu, and goes down till a particular specified height. (but the width is full).

I referred to the following but still no results:
[Starting a background image below navbar in Twitter Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11413671/starting-a-background-image-below-navbar-in-twitter-bootstrap). I am also not using any Bootstrap.

This is what I have coded so far but no results:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Numberz</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,600italic,700italic,400,600,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <nav>

       <img src="image2.png" alt="numberz" width="218px" height="38px" style="margin-left: 100px; margin-top: 15px; float: left; display: inline-block;">

       <section style="margin-right: 150px;">
         <ul id="menu">
            <li><a href="#"><b>SIGNUP</b></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><b>LOGIN</b></a></li>   
            <li><a href="#"><b>ACCOUNTANTS</b></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><b>BLOG</b></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><b>FEATURES</b></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><b>PRICING</b></a></li>
         </ul>
       </section>

    </nav>

    <div id="backgroundimage"></div> //this is the division created for the background image

  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
ul#menu li {
display: inline-block;
float: right;
position: relative;
margin-top: 28px; 
margin-left: 10px;
margin-right: 35px;

}

ul#menu li a {

text-decoration: none;
color: #808080;
font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
font-size: 15px;
}

#backgroundimage {
background: url("image3.png");
width: 1024px;
height: 500px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
display: block;
position: relative;
background-position: 0 500px;
}
```

Right now It looks like this:

[image]

I want something like this:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've tried your code. Try changing this line:

```
#backgroundimage {
background: url("image3.png");
width: 1024px;
height: 500px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
display: block;
position: relative;
background-position: 0 500px;
}
```

to this:

```
#backgroundimage {
background-image: url("image3.png");
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh; 
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
position: relative;
}
```

and then add this to your css:

```
nav
{
overflow: auto;
}
```

Here's a proof that it works:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with floating content is, its parent doesn't size with it.

Set your `nav` to `overflow: auto` will solve that.

*But I recommend to skip the `float: right` in the `ul#menu li` rule (as in 2.nd sample below)*

```css
ul#menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 28px; 
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 35px;
}

ul#menu li a {

  text-decoration: none;
  color: #808080;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
  font-size: 15px;
}

#backgroundimage {
  background: url("http://lorempixel.com/600/600/city");
  width: 1024px;
  height: 500px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: cover;
}
```

```html
<nav>

  <img src="image2.png" alt="numberz" width="218px" height="38px" style="margin-left: 100px; margin-top: 15px; float: left; display: inline-block;">

  <section style="margin-right: 150px;">
    <ul id="menu">
      <li><a href="#"><b>SIGNUP</b></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><b>LOGIN</b></a></li>   
      <li><a href="#"><b>ACCOUNTANTS</b></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><b>BLOG</b></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><b>FEATURES</b></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><b>PRICING</b></a></li>
    </ul>
  </section>

</nav>

<div id="backgroundimage"></div> //this is the division created for the background image
```

Sample without float

```css
ul#menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 28px; 
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 35px;
}

ul#menu li a {

  text-decoration: none;
  color: #808080;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
  font-size: 15px;
}

#backgroundimage {
  background: url("http://lorempixel.com/600/600/city");
  width: 1024px;
  height: 500px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: cover;
}
```

```html
<nav>

  <img src="image2.png" alt="numberz" width="218px" height="38px" style="margin-left: 100px; margin-top: 15px; float: left; display: inline-block;">

  <section style="margin-right: 150px;">
    <ul id="menu">
      <li><a href="#"><b>SIGNUP</b></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><b>LOGIN</b></a></li>   
      <li><a href="#"><b>ACCOUNTANTS</b></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><b>BLOG</b></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><b>FEATURES</b></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><b>PRICING</b></a></li>
    </ul>
  </section>

</nav>

<div id="backgroundimage"></div> //this is the division created for the background image
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, there was a issue with background-position,

```
#backgroundimage {
background:url(1.jpg);
margin-top:80px;
margin-left:100px;
width: 1024px;
height: 500px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
display: block;
position: absolute;
background-position:center;
background-size:cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just put the nav in a div and the image in another div so they get separated