# Displaying background image below navigation bar

Tags: html, css, image, navbar

I am trying to add a full sized background image below my navigation bar. Right now it is partially covering my background image.

I tried using this [Adding a background image just below the navigation bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38038056/adding-a-background-image-just-below-the-navigation-bar) but it did not change anything for me.

Right now my code is like this (CSS) :

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    background: #353535;
    font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 800;

    background-image: url(imageabc.png);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

My navigation bar is also in the  of my HTML codes:

```
<body>

    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <img src="imagebcd.png" alt="logo" class="logo"> <!-- logo image src -->

            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>

</body>
```

Could someone please help me identify what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set your `background-image` for the `body` it will be covered by the `navbar` as the navbar is part of the `body`. Simply set your `background-image` for a new `div`:

PS: you can play around with the settings of `background-position`, `background-size`, etc. according to your needs. Here is a good [link](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images_background.asp).

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    background: #353535;
    font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 800;

}

.full-size-img {
    background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/1150");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
        <header>
            <div class="container">
                <img src="imagebcd.png" alt="logo" class="logo"> <!-- logo image src -->
    
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div class="full-size-img">

        </div>
```